# What is the best method to call a Python 3.x program from within Python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm writing a Django web application. As of now, [Django does not support Python 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3). For the purposes of my web application, and without getting into to much detail, I essentially need to use some libraries that only support Python 3. Suffice it to say that after much thorough research no 2.x alternative was found.

So my question is this: How should I go about this?

I have both Python 2 and 3 installed on my server, and I have the Python 3 code written and waiting to be called. I was considering simply using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, effectively calling Python 3 from the command line, but the question is, is this the best method or is there a best practice I could use instead here? Using `subprocess` seems pretty hackish to me. Don't get me wrong, I'm okay with hackish, I just want to make sure there's nothing else I should be doing instead.

Comment: How about using [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/) and doing the whole thing in Python 3?

Comment: xmlrpc could be a simple alternative to subprocessing

Comment: Have you tried using the 3to2 program to see if the unspecified Python 3-only libraries can be converted to Python 2 automatically? Have you tried using Martin von Löwis' [port of Django to Python 3](https://bitbucket.org/loewis/django-3k/) so everything's running in Python 3?

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Yeah, so I'm not going to learn an entire new framework and rewrite our entire web application just to fix this one minor problem that I already have a fix for.

Comment: Adding Python 2 support is in 90% of the cases quite simple. You might  want to check with the library authors if you can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the Python 3 and Python 2 interpreters are totally separate executables and have separate libraries installed on your system, using `subprocess` to invoke one from the other *is* the best practice.  It's not a hack at all.  There are a number of ways to pass data between them but the two interpreters should be run as separate processes.

That said, you may need to keep in mind the startup time associated with launching an interpreter process.  That gets back to how to pass data between the two processes.  If your Python 2 code is going to be frequently calling the Python 3 routines, you may need to structure the Python 3 program as a daemon.  But you would still use `subprocess` to launch it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. As to whether it needs to end up as a process... that will take some thought. It only needs to be called once when a user signs up, so it may not need to be in the short term, but in theory, if my webapp were to become useful, it could be a convenient thing. The whole process should take no more than 5 seconds even if the Internet connection is really slow.

Answer (score 1):

Run the 3.x program as a separate service and then connect using some kind of RPC mechanism?